# Why is my render showing another old object inside an object?

Tags: objects

[image]

How do i remove the object inside the balloon-B object?

Comment: I'm guessing you have the object hidden in the viewport, but not disabled for renders. Objects hidden the viewport  (eye icon) will still be visible in renders if they are not disabled as well (camera icon). Another option is to move old objects to a separate collection then disable (not hide) the collection.

Comment: Go to the _Outliner_, select and delete the object.